# Asynchronous in dart

Tags: dart, asynchronous, future

On Dart DOC site I see this example of asyncronous,

```
    Future<void> printOrderMessage() async {
  print('Awaiting user order...');
  var order = await fetchUserOrder();
  print('Your order is: $order');
}

Future<String> fetchUserOrder() {
  return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), () => 'Large Latte');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  countSeconds(4);
  await printOrderMessage();
}

void countSeconds(int s) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: i), () => print(i));
  }
}


// output


Awaiting user order...
1                       // after 1 second
2                       // after 2 second
3                       //after 3 second
4                       // after 4 second
Your order is: Large Latte  // after 4 second
```

after I changed the code by convert return type of printOrderMessage() and main() to void
and remove async and await of main() , is output the same result

```
 printOrderMessage() async {
  print('Awaiting user order...');
  var order = await fetchUserOrder();
  print('Your order is: $order');
}

Future<String> fetchUserOrder() {
  return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), () => 'Large Latte');
}

  main() {
  countSeconds(4);
  printOrderMessage();
}

void countSeconds(int s) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: i), () => print(i));
  }
}
```

// output

```
Awaiting user order...
1                       // after 1 second
2                       // after 2 second
3                       //after 3 second
4                       // after 4 second
Your order is: Large Latte  // after 4 second
```

Why we ever need to sync and await in main()  and return type of Future, if show the same result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `async` and `await` in your `main`.
As written, it makes no difference.

It's *good practice* to not ignore asynchronous behavior, and using `async` and `await` here highlights that asynchrony is actually happening.

It doesn't matter for the behavior of *this* program because all the final `await printOrderMessage();` does is to receive a future from `printOrderMessage()`, wait for it to complete, then complete the `Future` returned by `main` (which it returns because of the `async`) with either `null` or the same error, if the awaited future completed with an error. No-one waits for the future returned by `main`, so any value-result is ignore and any error becomes an uncaught async error. And that's exactly the same that would happen if you just write `printOrderMessage();` without the `await` - the value is ignored and the error is uncaught.

If anyone had access to the future returned by `main` then you would see a difference - the `main` future would complete immediately without the `await`, instead of waiting, and it would not get the same errors (it can't, since it didn't wait for it). That makes `main` special, as the one function that no-one ever looks at the result of, and it's better to just get in the habit of awaiting all futures instead of worrying over whether you really need so in a `main` method.

And if the `await` wasn't the last operation of the `main` function, it would also matter, because the `await` delays everything afterwards. Here, there is nothing after the `await`.

Comment: Since `await` will pause the `main()` execution it will make a difference if there is some code to execute after the awaited function. It is not all about accessing the future returned by main(). See the last part of my answer. Unless I'm wrong your answer is quite misleading.

Comment: There is no code after the `await` in this program. If there was, then yes, omitting an await will change timing. The issue here is that the `await` is the *last* operation of the function, and  that no-one listens on the future returned by the function. The original question was why it made no difference to remove the `async` and `await`. I've added a comment saying that the `await` being last also matters.

Answer (score 1):

The `void` keyword is optional for a function that return null.
So is `Future<void>`.
They can be removed without changing anything.

`await` keyword will pause the execution of the async function until the awaited function return. In your example `printOrderMessage()` is at the last line of `main()`. It doesn't matter if it's awaited or not because there is no other code to execute after printOrderMessage() return.

If `printOrderMessage` is before `countSeconds`, the `await` keyword will change the output :

```
main() async {
  printOrderMessage();
  countSeconds(4);
}


main() async {
  await printOrderMessage();
  countSeconds(4);
}
```